# Perfetto Android trace "error stats for this trace"

Tags: android, profiling, trace, perfetto

I'm using [Perfetto](https://perfetto.dev/docs/quickstart/android-tracing) to profile my Android app. Everything works fine and I get a trace file, which I am able to convert into an SQLite3 database, extract measurements from and visualise the results.

However, my trace throws an error when it completes:

[image]

The settings for the trace are:

```
Target platform: Andriod P
Long trace, 1m30s duration, max file size 500mb

probes: CPU coarse usage counter with 1000ms poll interval, schedualing details
```

The settings are configured using the perfetto UI: https://ui.perfetto.dev/#!/record?p=buffers
Instructions are copied and pasted to the terminal on a Mac.

Any idea what the error is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a data loss in the central buffer, see
https://perfetto.dev/docs/concepts/buffers#debugging-data-losses

Either increase the size of the central buffer size (buffers->size or reduce the file_write_period_ms setting

Comment: Thanks - will give this a go!